# How to mix more than two shaders?

Tags: shaders

How can I go if I want to mix more than two shaders? Lets say that I have a diffuse and a glossy shader pluged onto a mix shader and than I want to put in a third shader (or more). How can I do that?

Comment: Couldn't you use another Mix shader? Mix two inputs with Fac 0.5, connect the output to a second Mix shader and set its Fac to 0.66. Use the third input for the second input (will use the remaining 0.33, each 1/3).

Comment: This ^^^ is correct.  The numbers in the answer below are incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

The mix shader only directly supports two inputs, as you've seen. But the easiest fix here is just to use two mix shaders:

[image]

- Mix Shader 1 takes Diffuse and Glossy as input.
- Mix Shader 2 takes Mix Shader 1 and another shader as input.

If you want to make the shaders evenly distributed, you could set Mix Shader 2's *Fac* value to `0.333` (assuming Mix Shader 1 is in the first slot) to give each shader one-third of the overall influence.

Comment: The numbers are incorrect...setting the Fac to 1 will use only the bottom shader.  Setting the second Mix Fac to .333 doesn't give the desired result.  The comment above from CoDEmanX is correct ^^^.  Try it with a red, green, and blue glass shader.  With the right numbers you should get a gray color.