# How can I layer my textures in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I am trying make a Victorian style dress for my model and I need a little help. I am trying to make shiny patterns using the nodes.I can't find any videos on this anywhere.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/how-to-mix-more-than-two-shaders and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: Or http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13600/599

Answer (score 2):

You can use a texture as a mixture factor.
[image]
Replace the noise texture with an image texture of you liking.

Change the diffuse for the fabric texture, and the glossy can be use for the shiny texture.

Answer (score 1):

The basic way to combine materials is using a node to mix the shaders.

There are two variations of those nodes: **Add Shader** and **Mix shader**. The main difference is that the mix shader node has an input for a factor to control the mix.

For what you want, as it's been pointed out on other answer, you can use a texture as a factor to control how the shaders mix. You can add as many **mix** or **add** shaders as you want for nuanced materials.

To generate the relief on the fabric, you can plug the texture to the **displacement** input of the material output node

[image]

[image]